# Replace some values of one MATLAB matrix with values from another

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm a new programmer, working in MATLAB, and I am hoping to substitute some values in one of my matrices with information from another matrix.

So, for example, supposing I have one matrix [A]:

```
A = [0  0  0  0  0  
    .5  0 .2 .8  0
     1 .3  1 .1 .1
     1  1 .4  1  1
     1  1  1  1  1]
```

And another matrix B:

```
B = [.4 .3 .2 .1 .2]
```

I would like to replace the first nonzero value in A with the one in the same column in matrix B such that:

```
A_new = [0  0  0  0  0  
        .4  0 .2 .1  0
         1 .3  1 .1 .2
         1  1 .4  1  1
         1  1  1  1  1]
```

There are some values between 0 and 1 that I want to keep untouched which precludes just changing everything between 0 and 1 (exclusive). I'm sure the solution will involve an if statement and possibly a for loop, but I'm not sure how to set it up. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[~, row] = max(A~=0);
A(row + (0:size(A,1):numel(A)-1)) = B
```

*How it works*:

The first line produces a vector `row` containing the index of the first nonzero row in each column. This use of `max` is a "*column-wise `find`*" of sorts. Namely, `max` works down each column and tells you the row index of the maximum value in that column. Since each column only contains `0` or `1`, there may be several maximizing (`1`) values; `max` gives the (index of) the *first* one.

In the second line that vector is transformed into a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) to replace those elements of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, though probably inefficient, is to use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and search for row and column locations that are non-zero.  Once you find this, because MATLAB searches for non-zero entries **column-wise**, you can apply [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to the column indices and find transitions.  The elements on the right-hand of the transition denote the first non-zero value for each column.  Once you find these locations, get the corresponding row locations for these entries, create a new matrix `A_new` that is a copy of `A`, then change the corresponding entries to `B`.  You'll need to use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) for the assignment.

Something like this:

```
%// Define matrix
A = [0  0  0  0  0  
    .5  0 .2 .8  0
     1 .3  1 .1 .1
     1  1 .4  1  1
     1  1  1  1  1];

%// Find non-zero entries
[row,col] = find(A);

%// Figure out the column locations that are the first non-zero for each column
ind = diff([Inf; col]) ~= 0;

%// Create a new matrix that is a copy of the old one
A_new = A;

%// Create the B vector
B = [.4 .3 .2 .1 .2];

%// Do the assignment
A_new(sub2ind(size(A), row(ind), (1:size(A,2)).')) = B;
```

Doing `sub2ind` is perhaps inefficient because there is a lot error checking done and that can slow things down.  You can compute the linear indices manually by:

```
columns = size(A,2);
A_new((0:columns-1).'*columns + row(ind)) = B;
```

Running the above code, we get:

```
>> A

A =

         0         0         0         0         0
    0.5000         0    0.2000    0.8000         0
    1.0000    0.3000    1.0000    0.1000    0.1000
    1.0000    1.0000    0.4000    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000

>> A_new

A_new =

         0         0         0         0         0
    0.4000         0    0.2000    0.1000         0
    1.0000    0.3000    1.0000    0.1000    0.2000
    1.0000    1.0000    0.4000    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```